# Trying to Create a Manager Hierarchy

Tags: python

I am trying to create manager levels and I am getting stuck on the proper approach. I am using a csv file and have imported pandas and numpy, I want to take the "Manager 1" as the start and then show how many levels away the rest of the managers are from them. Below is an example of what I mean.

```
Employee_ID     Manager_1        Manager_2      Reporting_Managers 
 101             111               112               112                  
 102             111               102               111                
 103             111               118               300
```

So the goal is to have the Reporting Manager be the tested one and if the the reported manager is not on the list then they fall to lowest manager level (manager level 3) Something Like this:  '

```
Employee_ID        Manager_1        Manager_2     Reporting_Manager     Level_of_Reporting_MGR
    101               111              112              112                      2
    102               111              102              111                      1
    103               111              118              300                      3
```

I have tried using a for loop and iterating through the reporting managers but I am not sure if that is the right approach or not. I am new to coding so this may be simple but I am not sure.

Current code looks like this:

```
 Level_of_Reporting_MGR = []
 for num in df['Manager_']:
     if num in df['Manager_1']:
        Level_of_Reporting_MGR.append(1)
     elif num in df['Manager_2']:
        Level_of_Reporting_MGR.append(2)
     else:
        Level_of_Reporting_MGR.append(3)
 df['Level_of_Reporting_MGR'] = Level_of_Reporting_MGR
```

Comment: What are these? JSON blobs? CSV files? Pandas dataframes? There's no Python code here and no indication of what these ASCII-formatted tables *mean* in Python.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I am using a csv fie importing pandas and numpy, I have updated the file with code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not had a chance to try this out properly, but here's an outline of how I might approach the job.

```
def manager_score(series):
    sweep_list = ["Manager_1", "Manager_2"]
    for e,m in enumerate(sweep_list):
        if series['Reporting_Manager']==series[m]:
            return e + 1
    return len(sweep_list)

df['distance'] = df.apply(manager_score, axis=1)
```